# How can I fix this simple do/while loop?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, cs50

I've looked at multiple questions with the same issue, but unfortunately they have different kinds of problems with their loops.

I would like the code to output "This is long enough" when a user has inputted text longer than one char.

Every time I input something, I get prompted again for an answer.

I'm new to c and I'm not sure what I messed up on.

```
int length;

do
{
    string text = get_string("INPUT:");
    length = strlen(text);
}

while(length >= 1);

printf("This is long enough.");
```

Comment: Before anyone peppers you with "what is `get_string` ? and is `string` a C or C++ thing", you should probably let everyone know you're using the `cs50` header and library (neither of which are at-all helpful, imho, for people learning C, especially since they hide `char *` in the type alias `string` right out of the gate, and it only gets worse from there). Related what does `while(length >= 1);` mean to you, specifically as it relates to the conditions under which you intend to *continue* your loop vs. break from it?

Comment: The problem is in the code you're not showing.

Comment: This is all the code I have so far

Comment: C doesn't have `string`, nor `get_string()`. If this is all you got it doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while condition is wrong. Your loop will run until the user inputs text less than one char (ie no text). Remember the loop will run as long as the condition is true. Instead do:

```
while(length <= 1);
```

This will run as long as your string is one char or less and stop when you have more than one char.

Comment: @iraza-n Have a look at [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It is a must read for anyone learning to program. It helps you gain a mindset for approaching problems in your code.